# Updating client's CentOS on WebHostManager from CentOs 5.11 to latest version?

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, web-hosting

I was wondering how I'd go about updating a client's CentOS on a WebHostManager install from CentOS 5.11 to the latest version?

Just have never dealt with updating CentOS, so I'm kind of not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean from CentOS 5.11 to 7.4 ? That means reinstallation...

Comment: Oh, there's no way to just, update? That's odd.

Comment: Actually there is the option: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964 However it's without support and in case you use some 3rd party packages, you may get into dependency hell. Much safer way is reinstallation.